# how to convert json array result object as non array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json result of latitude longiude as an array result like this, [13.0801721, 80.2838331] .
I want to convert this just as comma seprated valueswithout array brackets lik this, 13.0801721, 80.2838331. Please help

Here is my problem.

i want to get this array of 
`var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng([13.0801721, 80.2838331]);` json result like this

```
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0801721, 80.2838331);
```

please see screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoVyE.png)

Comment: `13.0801721` doesn't look like integer

Comment: Did you do any research of your own? Problem seems pretty trivial. I'm sure googling this will provide an answer.

Comment: i tried by googling but end all results like string

Comment: Did you try getting the value and aplying parseInt() on it ?

Comment: yes it outputs values before decimal point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your function like this:

```
 let result=[13.0801721, 80.2838331];
 let myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(...result);
```

This uses the [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)